# React component self state (UI state)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using React-toolbox dialog and I want to wrap it as a simple confirmation dialog, where it works like a `alert()`  show the dialog with a message and a close button.

so I have my presentational component like this

```
const ConfirmationDialog =({active, size, title,  message}) => {

  const onClickConfirm = ()=> {
    active = false;
  }

  return (
      <Dialog
        active={active}
        title={title}
        type={size}
      >
        <p>{message}</p>
          <button onClick={onClickConfirm}>Close</button>
      </Dialog>
  );
}

export default ConfirmationDialog;
```

The `active` comes from a props so the confirmation dialog will shown when I need it, however I would like the close button to just self close the dialog.

Do I really have to pass a `handleOnClose` function? it seems too redundant having to pass that function each time I want to use this component.
or do I really have to create a container class to achieved a such simple action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your `ConfirmationDialog` component as class and use local state to store there `active` variable:

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class ConfirmationDialog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Setting `active` state property from props.
    this.state = {
      active: props.active,
    };

    // As we are passing this function as event handler, we need bind context,
    // to get access to `this` inside this function.
    this.handleCloseClick = this.handleCloseClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // When we will provide `active` variable via props, we will automatically set it to state.
    if (nextProps.active !== this.props.active) {
      this.setState({
        active: nextProps.active,
      });
    }
  }

  handleCloseClick() {
    // On clicking `close` button, setting `active` state variable to `false`,
    // it forces component to rerender with new state.
    this.setState({
      active: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { title, size, message } = this.props;
    // Getting `active` variable from state, instead of props.
    const { active } = this.state;
    return (
      <Dialog
        active={active}
        title={title}
        type={size}
      >
        <p>{message}</p>
        <button onClick={this.handleCloseClick}>Close</button>
      </Dialog>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: I can not get your code working :S. when ever `props.active` changes, it's not getting rerendered, so even I change the active props to true, the windows is not rendered now :S

Comment: @Kossel see updated answer, I added `componentWillReceiveProps` method to set `active` variable to state, when props are changed.

Answer (score 0):

You're directly modifying props in your code. I wonder if this code works. Because it shouldn't.

You need to store `active` thingy somewhere in the component's state, either this one or (most likely) at the upper level component.

And as it seems easy, it's really not *that* easy with React. Check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@gaperton/state-and-forms-in-react-part-3-handling-the-complex-state-acf369244d37#.e7a4zxlmw), here I'm explaining how to do [things like that](https://volicon.github.io/NestedLink/) with modal pop-ups.

Comment: Hi, actually it's not working because props can not be changed. why the active state should be in a upper level component instad of this component?

Comment: It might be in _this_ component too, but (assuming we're talking about the generic dialog wrapper) in this case you won't open the dialog again when it will be closed. Because you cannot directly access the state from the upper component, which open the dialog.

Thus, this open/closed state must be propagated upper to the component which actually decides whenever this confirmation dialog must be opened.

Comment: Well, in fact you can. If you make a _ref_ to this dialog from the upper level, you can modify its state. Possible, but _not_ recommended. You could try both options to feel how they differs.